# Anyone needing Australian Ambiences?

Tags: australia, ambience, sonic

hi everyone, really enjoying the social sound experience.
just to let you all know, i operate  a professional ambience recording recording service specifically catering to designers/editors who need authentic Australian ambiences. it's called Sonic *Australis*.
any suggestions, needs or thoughts on this service are happily fielded. 
looking forward to being of service to you.
all the best, kingsley

Answer (score 2):

You need a decent website and establish your presence (no pun intended) with Google.  I did a search for "Australian backgrounds", "Austrian backgrounds sound", and "Australian sound effects" and your name never came up.  If I was looking for authentic Australian effects Google would be step one. Right now I would think Sounddogs was the only source. I think there's a market for what you have, just get your name on the search engines.

Comment: I must also agree, in that I tried his website link from his profile (both as a .com and the .au just in case) and neither kicked back a valid domain.  I'd be interested too, just need to know where to find the destination! :)

Comment: The link on the profile seems to work ok for me

Comment: hi guys, thanks a million for the replies and helpful advice. duly taken and considered. sorry about the link dramas... not sure what happened there. anyways, stay tuned, lots of australian sounds to emerge in the coming months...